# How do I match multiple attributes of a model to one set of search keywords in 1 where statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some basic search implemented and I am trying to match multiple attribute to the 1 set of keywords.

I have this:

```
listings = Listing.order(:headline)
listings = listings.where("headline like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
```

I have multiple attributes for `listings` that I would like to check to see if the `keywords` appear in - e.g. say `listing.neighborhood.name` or `listing.type.name`.

How do I write all of that in 1 statement? I tried:

```
listings = listings.where("headline like ? or neighborhood.name like ?", "%#{keywords}%")
```

But that returned this error:

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: headline like ? or neighborhood.name like ?
```

One obvious solution is just to add `"%#{keywords}%"` again...but that hardly seems DRY.

How do I add check both the `neighborhood.name` and `type.name` and others in that 1 query? Or should I be approaching this another way?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

When I try the non-DRY way of simply adding another `{keywords}` parameter, this is the error I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: neighborhood.name: SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings"  WHERE (headline like '%sterling place%') AND (headline like '%sterling place%' or neighborhood.name like '%sterling place%') ORDER BY headline.
```

Which I think is because `neighborhood` is a foreign_key on my `listings` model, and not an attribute in and of itself. There is a simple association between the `listings` & `neighborhood` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (still a non-DRY way) :

```
key = "%#{keywords}%"
listings = Listing.includes(:neighborhood).where("headline like ? or neighborhoods.name like ?", key, key)
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks meng! Although, it would be nice if this could be DRY-ed up, but you got the essence of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Quick question, why do I get this error on Heroku, but not in development: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'neighborhoods' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?` This works locally, but when I push to Heroku that's the error I am getting in the console. Thoughts?

Comment: I broke out this error to a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814126/heroku-join-includes-not-working-like-sqlite-dev-environment

Comment: OK fine, hope you'll find a solution soon and glad I could help you until now!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have many option to make it DRY... but you could do something like:

```
listings = listings.where("headline like :keywords or neighborhood.name like :keywords", :keywords => "%#{keywords}%")
```

**Edit**: I didn't realise the association... [siekfried](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517876/siekfried) is right... just a little more DRY if you start adding more columns:

```
listings = Listing.includes(:neighborhood).where("listings.headline like :keywords or neighborhoods.name like :keywords", :keywords => "%#{keywords}%")
```

Comment: The issue I seem to be bumping up against is the association (i.e. matching the keywords to the `neighborhood.name`). Is it possible to match a keyword to an association like that? Or do I have to do it in a different where clause? When I tested your suggestion, I got the error I put in my question under `Edit 1`.

Comment: oh...sorry, I didn't realise the association... you will need `includes` or `joins` as per siekfried's answer.

Comment: Btw, I like this solution, but now I am getting this error on Heroku - `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "neighborhood"`. Thoughts?

Comment: change :neighborhood to :neighborhoods... it must be the table name.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'neighborhoods' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`. :|

Comment: Btw, I broke this out to a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814126/heroku-join-includes-not-working-like-sqlite-dev-environment

Comment: I posted a new answer in the new post... when it goes to SQL I think the table name must be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
listings = listings.where("headline like ? or neighborhood.name like ?", "%#{keywords}%", "%#{keywords}%")
```

Comment: See updates to the question. I addressed in the original question and in the update.